# How to check last time keep-alive packet received

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client, keep-alive

I send keep-alive packets from server to client.

server know when client die.

But how i can check connection in client? send keep-alive too?

Or i can check last time keep-alive packet received from server?

Comment: Personally, I like to do it the other way. Have the client send a keep-alive periodically, and have the server respond to it. If a client doesn't send anything to the server for awhile, the server can assume that client is dead and close its end of the connection. If the client doesn't receive a response from the server, the client can assume the server is dead and close its end of the connection

Comment: yes. but how i can check that server or client send keep-alive?

Comment: That is the responsibility of each party to keep track of as needed. There is no standard to this. Do whatever makes sense for your code. The server could track the time of the last packet received from the client, and close the connection if the interval from that time elapses too long. The client could do the same, while sending keep-alives periodically.